# Changing bootstrap-progress bar with carousel

Tags: jquery, css, html, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I'm trying to change the bootstrap-progress bar as it transitions with the slides.

for instance..

```
slide 1 = 16%
slide 2 = 32%
slide 3 = 48%
```

and so on and so forth.

So far, I've been able to figure out how to make the value change, but only with a checkbox. Please help me out. I

The code is provided here:
http://www.bootply.com/vRKotQ1Ptc

Answer (score 2):

First you have to set a interval for the carousel, is `data-interval="5000"` as default, but is better to define it when you want use Jquery and get this value.

```
<div class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" id="quote-carousel" data-interval="5000">
```

Then you have to deactivacte the effect of `.progress-bar` in the CSS.

```
.progress-bar {
  background-color:#F0A340!important;
    -webkit-transition: none;
    -moz-transition: none;
    -ms-transition: none;
    -o-transition: none;
    transition: none;
}
```

Now you can code your function to fill the progress-bar. I write the code in `$(document).ready(function()` to execute it as the same time of the start of carousel timer(when the page is loaded). I would use `setInterval`, to execute the same code each "x" ms. I wrote `50 ms` and `i++;` because I think the visual effect is better.
But you can modify it as you wish, like `500 ms` and `i+=10`. You just have to calculate a multiple of `data-interval` to define the interval to fill the progress-bar.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var i = 0;
  setInterval(function() {
    $('.progress-bar').css('width', i + '%').css('value', i);
    i++;
    if(i==100)
      i = 0;
    console.log(i);
}, 50);
});
```

I hope that was helpfull.

Comment: This is great, but it is just a running progress bar.

Comment: Yes, is a running progress bar synchronized with the slide. Maybe I understood bad what you want ?

Comment: Oh sorry. I see what you mean. However, it isn't what I was looking for. For example, if the slide is at 1, then the max progress bar is 16%, then slide 2, 33%, slide 3, 50%, etc etc. Slide 6 is the max though, and when it hits slide 1 again, it resets to 0%. Essentially, it's progress through the slides.

Comment: Sorry too, I had not well understood. Do you want it only for 6 slide or dynamic ?

Comment: yes, so the arrows make the the bar progress, and move the slide as well.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is the value of `valuer` variable which you used as the % of progress bar. When a slide change what bootstrap does is, it add a `active` class to that `div`. So give the `id` of `div` with `item` class as the % of bar progressed and take it by taking value of `id` attribute of the class `active`. You have to do it with the same interval as they are using to change the slide.

Answer (score 0):

First. Always put your code here. And ofcourse the link provided is nice.

This is your jquery problem

```
    $('input').on('click', function(){
  var valeur = 0;
  $('input:checked').each(function(){
       if ( $(this).attr('value') > valeur )
       {
           valeur =  $(this).attr('value');
       }
  });
  $('.progress-bar').css('width', valeur+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', valeur);
});
```

Your html problem

```
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
            <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="20" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100">
            </div>
          </div>
```

Now. this may be your solution to your problem. Make a function out of it.

```
function newProgress(value){
          $('.progress-bar').css('width', value+'%').attr('aria-valuenow', value);
};
```

When running the slide you call the function. And change the value. like

```
    //running slider here
var data = "90"; //<=== Put here your %
    var value$('.progress-bar').attr('value', data);
//now you call the function
newProgress(value );
```

Comment: my jquery is not that great, do you mind showing it in a jsfiddle of bootply?